# How to write tests for a multi-threaded producer-consumer C program?

Tags: c, multithreading, testing, gdb

How does one write good tests for a multi-threaded producer-consumer C program?

I know GDB can be used to debug threads, but I believe GDB also stops the thread currently being debugged while other threads continue running.

I want to test proper mutex lucking/unlocking and blocking by my threads. I've looked around a lot but haven't been able to find any good resources.

I have unit tests for all the non-concurrent functionality, but want to make sure my concurrency is correct. How can this be done?

Comment: I don't believe some universal solutuon exist. In general you should do the same thing as to single thread code, that is test all combinations. may be if you post concrete small example one could find an answer for a particular case

Comment: To my knowledge, testing concurrency is incredibly tricky, especially on modern systems that run in the gigahertz region.  For anything small especially, it's relatively easier if you try to prove algorithmic correctness *first* and then write the code.  I'll second @Lol4t0 in that there's not likely a universal solution.

Comment: @tonysdg, I believe researching algorithm for correctness is the one step but you also have to check if your implementation is consistent with the algorithm you developed.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe GDB also stops the thread currently being debugged while other threads continue running.

Your belief is mistaken: by default GDB works in `all-stop` mode: stopping one thread stops them *all*.

Newer GDB versions do also have `non-stop` mode, in which other threads continue to run, but that is not the default.

> want to make sure my concurrency is correct.

It is *impossible* to prove that concurrency is correct through testing. You can only do that by writing correct code (and reviewing it carefully).

Clang [thread safety analysis](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html) can help. Testing under [thread sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) can help. GDB is generally the wrong tool here.